# how to add yyyy/MM date in drop down list in webforms c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, webforms

I'm new in c# webforms. I'm experimenting drop down list. I want to load the current year and  month, and it's two months ago months. I want to display YEAR and MONTH only.
example: date now - 2017 / 03. two months ago are - 2017 / 02 and 2017 / 01.

default.aspx:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartPeriod" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

on my page_load in default.aspx.cs:

> ddlStartPeriod.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy / MM"));

I don't know what's the next move and I don't how to subtract 2 months from DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy / MM").

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyy / MM")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
 ListItem li = new ListItem(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM"), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM"));
            ddlStartPeriod.Items.Add(li);
            ListItem li2 = new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy/MM"), DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy/MM"));
            ddlStartPeriod.Items.Add(li2);
            ListItem li3 = new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyy/MM"), DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyy/MM"));
            ddlStartPeriod.Items.Add(li3);
```

Comment: What if date now is - 2017 / 01, so the past two months will be, 2016 / 12 and 2016 / 11. is your code will get an error?

Comment: You can check it will not give error it will get 2016/12 and 2016/11

Comment: you can change your system date time to 2017/01 and check logic

Answer (score 1):

Simple just add **dataTextFormatString** attribute.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartPeriod" runat="server" dataTextFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM}"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**OR**

ddlStartPeriod.DataTextFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM}";

more detail for date format so refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).